# Unreasonably high requirement for the size of the dataset for a simple neural network implementation in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am trying to use `scikit-learn` for a very simple dateset to have a taste on how neural network works. The structure is very simple. Each data point has only one parameter, time, and the output is index. I fit the points with linear regression before hand and get the slope = 6.474 and the y-intercept as 36.768. The original dataset only contains 13 points (time from 2 to 14). Therefore, I artifically made up an arbitrary dataset size by creating the datapoints by `index = 6.474*time + 36.768 + e` where e is noise term ranging from -1.5 to 1.5 (with `2<time<14` to mimic the original dataset).

Here's my code on python:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
import numpy as np

size = 100
np.random.seed(0)
time = np.array(np.random.rand(size,1) * 14)
np.random.seed(1)

index = (time * 6.474 + 36.768) + 3*(np.random.rand(size,1)-0.5)
index = [x[0] for x in index]

regr = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes = (1,)).fit(time, index)
print(regr.predict([[15], [16], [17], [18]]))
```

I set the hidden layer to one because it should be equivalent to finding a best fitting straight line. After training the model, I try to predict the output for four inputs (time): `15,16,17,18`. Surprisingly, as shown in the attached figure, the performance of the neural network is terrible until I increase the dataset size to 10000. I expect a dataset of 10, or absolutely no more than 100 should do the job well given such a simple relationship. I wonder what is the reason for the poor performance?

[image: Prediction by the neural network of different training set size]

Comment: *"I expect a dataset of 10, or absolutely no more than 100 should do the job well given such a simple relationship." * - And what is the basis of your expectations? Why do you expect MLPRegressor successfully predict values outside the range it has seen in training?

Comment: For the first question: Because I saw an MLP classifier example of training the NN to recognize a handwritten number (0 to 9 of 32x32 pixel). with about 900 input images, the NN can already have an accuracy of about 90%, so I expect my dataset can be smaller in this simple case. For the second question, for a single node, single hidden layer, the output of the NN is equivalent to y = ax+b, where a is the weight of the node from the training. Even if I do not predict out of the range (i.e. 2 to 14), the result is equally terrible (you can image interpolating the dots from x>15 back to x<14).

Comment: A model with a single hidden layer, with a nonlinear activation function, is _not_ a linear function. You are confusing this with a network with _no_ hidden layers. Worse, the default activation is `relu` which can completely cut off the gradient for half the input space, which in turn makes learning extremely difficult (as you observe).

Comment: Thank you @xdurch0, I thought the default activation function is the identity function. I just tried to add an argument to the MLPregressor `activation = 'identity'`. However, the training result for a 1000 dataset is still not satisfactory.